# Variable memoir TOC page number box size

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir

My book long front matter page numbers which were sticking out into the margin. Following the `memoir` documentation, it was easy to remedy this, as in the MWE which follows.

The documentation (§9.2.2) says that:

> "the length used in `\setrmarg` should be greater than the length set in `\setpnumwidth`. These values should remain constant in any given document".

It makes sense not to have all kinds of variation, but this means that in my case at least, many pages of TOC have a huge `pnumwidth` (and thus sacrifice width for the entries) due to a few lines of long Roman numerals.

[image]

I tried a smaller `setrmarg`, and this does allow for longer entries, but it doesn't seem to affect the dots, which still stop before the page number box.

So what I would like to do is to restrict the increased `pnumwidth` to the front matter (which, coincidentally, does not have dots).

MWE:

```
 \documentclass[%
    a4paper,
    11pt,
    twoside,
    one column,
    openright
    ]{memoir}

\setpnumwidth{3.55em}
\setrmarg{5.55em}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\setcounter{page}{33}
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage

\listoffigures
\cleardoublepage

\listoftables
\cleardoublepage

\mainmatter
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{chapter}--\arabic{figure}}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{chapter}--\arabic{table}}
\section{Section}
The section.
\begin{table}
\caption{Table}
Table contents
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

EDIT: I tried the first approach, putting the `\resetpnum` right after `\mainmatter`, and the result was peculiar: the box did get reset, but not until a chapter later (in my main file, with multiple chapters and appendices.

[image]

Second EDIT: using the longer solution involving `\etoolbox`, with the same result. Lines from the `.toc` follow:

```
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.10.4}Remarks regarding presentation}{20}{subsection.1.10.4}
\defcounter {refsection}{0}\relax
\def \@pnumwidth {0.55em}\def \@tocrmarg {1.55em}
\defcounter {refsection}{0}\relax
\contentsline {chapter}{\chapternumberline {2}Larsa/Senkereh}{21}{chapter.2}
```

EDIT3 (apparent solution):
Having noted some remarks in the `memoir` documentation, section 9.2, page 156 (version v3.7f, 2016/05/16), I tried the code below, which seemed work:

```
...
\frontmatter
\setcounter{page}{5}% as per Olms format requirements 
\cftlocalchange{toc}{3.55em}{5.55em}
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage

\listoffigures
\cleardoublepage

\listoftables
\cftlocalchange{toc}{1.55em}{2.55em}
\cleardoublepage
...
```

Comment: As far as I remember, there is no per type interface for this. But we can probably hack something a bit more manually. Where exactly do you want two different rmargs? Just one in the frontmatter and another in the rest of the doc (where the page numbers are more similar?)

Comment: @daleif Yes, exactly so. The front matter has the long roman numerals, everything else can be one measure (so far, the default is fine). The current max is around 500 and it's not going to reach 1000....

Comment: Not at pc, I'll add a suggestion tomorrow

Comment: @daleif Great. I can't work on this today either, anyway. When I get back to it it occurred to me I could try the 'brute force' approach and prepend to the figure list, table list, etc., but even if it works that's a bit crude....

Comment: We can add hooks to the toc, just have to do it in the right way

Comment: Where exactly does Jons solution not work, please update with a specific MWE. Also note your edit3 mentions `\printshorthands` where does that come from?

Comment: @daleif Jon's solution works for the MWE illustrating the original problem, it does not work when applied to my actual (very complicated) file, as shown by the clip above: the correction happens but not at the place where the correction code is inserted. The `\printshorthands` is from my main file, I will edit and remove that.

Comment: you should make an MWE where it dows not work, otherwise it is very hard to help (we cannot keep guessing forever)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is probably how I would do it. Using `\cftlocalchange`, is one way, but this leaves the values used in the body of the text, I like to keep layout stuff in the preamble (or in a separate package).

Instead I use memoirs build in toc hook system to insert hooks (macros) to be executed from within the toc. Note that this means that we cannot use `\cftlocalchange` as it writes to the toc, and the hook runs from within the toc. Thus we simply do by hand, what `\cftlocalchange` would add to the toc.

Note that these changes are global in this case. I you do not want this, place `\tableofcontens` inside a group.

```
\documentclass[%
    a4paper,
    11pt,
    twoside,
    one column,
    openright
    ]{memoir}


% define what the hooks do
% we cannot use \cftlocalchange as this hook is added inside the toc
% and \cftlocalchange writes to the toc
\cftinsertcode{FRONTMATTER}{%
  \protect\setpnumwidth{3.55em}
  \protect\setrmarg{5.55em}
}

\cftinsertcode{MAINMATTER}{%
  \protect\setpnumwidth{2.55em}
  \protect\setrmarg{3.55em}
}


\begin{document}

\cftinserthook{toc}{FRONTMATTER}
\frontmatter
\setcounter{page}{33}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Test in frontmatter}

\section{Test}



\cleardoublepage

\listoffigures
\cleardoublepage

\listoftables
\cleardoublepage

\cftinserthook{toc}{MAINMATTER}
\mainmatter
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{chapter}--\arabic{figure}}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{chapter}--\arabic{table}}
\section{Section}
The section.
\begin{table}
\caption{Table}
Table contents
\end{table}

 \end{document}
```

Comment: I have just road-tested this and it works fine, much appreciated. I still don't know why Jon's original solutions only half-worked, but I suspect that it would take a lot of work to generate a somewhat minimal example to reproduce the secondary problem and a lot of time from you folk. So I'm content to accept this for now and perhaps the other will become clearer as I learn.

Answer (score 1):

The key is to write to the `.toc` at the point you want to change `\@pnumwidth` and `\@tocrmarg`. You could do it like this:

Create the command `\resetpnum`:

```
\newcommand\resetpnum{%
\addtocontents{toc}{%
 % I think these are the default values
 \string\def\string\@pnumwidth{1.55em}%
 \string\def\string\@tocrmarg{2.55em}%
}}
```

Then you either issue `\resetpnum` where you want to, or use `etoolbox` to append the command to something like `\mainmatter`:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\appto\mainmatter{\resetpnum}
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass[%
    a4paper,
    11pt,
    twoside,
    one column,
    openright
    ]{memoir}

\setpnumwidth{3.55em}
\setrmarg{5.55em}

\newcommand\resetpnum{%
\makeatletter
\addtocontents{toc}{%
 \string\def\string\@pnumwidth{0.55em}%
 \string\def\string\@tocrmarg{1.55em}%
}
\makeatother
}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\appto\mainmatter{\resetpnum}


\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\setcounter{page}{33}
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage

\listoffigures
\cleardoublepage

\listoftables
\cleardoublepage

\mainmatter

\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{chapter}--\arabic{figure}}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{chapter}--\arabic{table}}
\section{Section}
The section.
\begin{table}
\caption{Table}
Table contents
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Produces a `.toc` file that looks like this:

```
\contentsline {chapter}{Contents}{xxxiii}
\contentsline {chapter}{List of Figures}{xxxv}
\contentsline {chapter}{List of Tables}{xxxvii}
\def \@pnumwidth {0.55em}\def \@tocrmarg {1.55em}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {0.1}Section}{1}
```

Comment: I'll give this a try!

Comment: The first solution did not quite work, see edit above. Will have to try the other one.

Comment: The second, fuller solution, didn't work either, same result as shown in the edit. Of course, I'm trying this on my actual (very complicated) file, not the MWE. It works fine on the MWE. I'm adding another edit with lines from the `.toc` file which match the visual result. I can't imagine what is causing the 'delayed reaction'.

Comment: Next tried a `\preto\chapter` instead of the `\appto` and had the reverse problem: the chapters were ok but the shorthand list (last front matter item) was hanging into the margin again. Clearly there's something more to the sequence of events here, but I don't know how to hook into the correct chronological sequence....

Comment: Hmm, well, as you note, it works as expected on the example you've provided. And, according to the snippet of the `.toc` you've provided, it is getting written to the `.toc` as expected. I think your example is, in this case, **too** minimal. Can you expand on it some?  The command `\addtocontents{toc}{<text>}` writes to the `.toc` at exactly the place it is called (as you can probably tell)....

Comment: Yes, I can work on this tomorrow. The MWE showed the problem and I did not anticipate the side-effect. I don't know all the details of the sequence of things and it may be that a package is throwing a spanner into the works.... however, the `.toc` is not actually being written as expected. Your patch updates the `\mainmatter` and it is being written to the file between chapters 1 and 2 (in my main file) rather than before chapter 1 as one would expect. That's the point of the snapshot in the edit :( It does, however, correspond to the output.

Comment: Yes, there is something strange going on. If there is no "privacy" or copyright issue, pending the construction of an actual MWE, perhaps posting the skeleton of the actual (master) `.tex` file and the resulting `.toc` file may help shed light on the issue. (The first of these may not be much less tedious to create than an actual MWE, so I leave that up to you.)

Comment: I can do that. Do I add to the original post as an edit? On another note, I see in section 9.2, page 156 of the current `memoir` documentation:  some interesting stuff about `\cftlocalchange` apparently for just this purpose....

Comment: Ah, yes. Upon inspection, that is the 'memoir' way to do it, I see. It does essentially the same thing as my command: `\cftlocalchange` writes an `\addtocontents` line. But it `\protect`s the `\setpnumwidth` and  `\setrmarg` commands, so it is probably better overall. I will revise answer.

Comment: Just tried it, seemed to work, so updated my original with the code used. Not sure how to best close this off (assuming there's no other angle that ought to be discussed).

Comment: I think you can (and should) post an answer to your question if it is a viable answer. (Out of an general academic interest, I'd like to see why `\cftlocalchange` works and my lower-level approach does not in your document, but no one else may care, and I can live with the mystery unanswered, so don't feel obliged to spend any more work on this on my account.)

Comment: Unless the OP provides an MWE which shows that your solution does not work, the idea is ok. But the `\makeatletter/atother` goes out side the macro desinition. And using `\protect` is the proper way to go, and it is probably not a good idea to set `\@pnumwidth` by hand, better use proper interfaces.

Comment: @jon In principle, I'm also curious. Should we take this to offside discussion? (Just not sure how to make that happen except when the site suggests it...)

Comment: @daleif -- The `\makeatletter/atother` are not needed if writing to the `.toc` (they are remnants of an older test; meant to take them out, but forgot), and `\protect\def\@pnumwidth{<...>}` will not work for this application. But I agree that one should use the appropriate hooks if they are available (as in `memoir`); however, usually they are not and I did not think to look. (Though as a long-time user of `memoir`, I should've known better!)

Comment: @K.G.Feuerherm -- I think we need to create a chat group, but I've never done so. I'm game to explore the issue if you are, however.

Comment: ... however, I see that `\def\protect\@pnumwidth{...}` works, which goes to show, I guess, that I have a lot to learn about `\protect`ion....

Comment: Whenever you are messing with macros with @ in the name, and you are not inside a package, you should be defining the macro under makeat

Comment: @jon Out all day, just saw your response. Sure... if we can figure it out.... Alternatively, is there a PM system so we can exchange info off-site?